# Reading rich text from Access in to Word

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, richtext

I have memo fields in an access 2007 database that are set up as rich text – both in the field and on the form – and I need to get these in to Word and preserve the formatting.  I have seen various solutions on StackOverflow recommending saving to a file (this didn’t format the text) and using IE (error with ExecCommand “copy”), the solution I have found that works for most cases is to use the clipboard, but I can’t get it to work for all types of formatting.

A few more details:  I am connecting to the database from Word using AdoDB, reading the data out in to an array.  From there copy the data to the clipboard and then I use Pastespecial – see solution from Microsoft Support http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;274326

The code to connect to Access is here (but I believe this is pretty std):

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strCon As String

'define connection
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'connect string for Access - no password
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strDataBaseFilePath & ";Persist Security Info=False;"

'open connection
cn.Open strCon

'get recordset
Set rs = cn.Execute(strSQL)

'load data into array
LoadDataFromDatabase = rs.GetRows
```

The code to Pastespecial the text in to Word is here:

```
PutHTMLClipboard CStr(varData)
rge.PasteSpecial datatype:=WdPasteDataType.wdPasteHTML
```

'PutHTMLClipboard is the Microsoft routine, vardata is defined as a variant and holds the data from one rich text field in Access.

Using this approach I get a few anomalies:

1. text which has custom bullets (e.g. in my situation  ’>’ rather than a standard dot) gets changed to a strange character
2. underlined text is formatted correctly, but if the text is bold + underline then only the bold formatting is set.  Bold + coloured font works OK though.

If I manually highlight the text in the Access form and copy and paste it directly in to Word then all the formatting is preserved perfectly.

Comment: What is your end goal? Access to Word to Web? Why not just output the rich text formatted memos into PDF via an Access report? All browsers today are PDF-compliant and render them directly in their windows. Plus in web design today styling fonts (bold, italicize, underline) and pages (lists, margins, padding, images) through html markup is a deprecated practice as css is the standard. Let us know your ultimate endpoint so we can help.

Comment: the aim is produce a completely formatted document in Word, pulling in user-selected records/fields as required - e.g. for Doc 1 you may need records 1, 2, 7, 15 with fields of description, client, date.  In Doc 2 it may be a completely different set of records / fields.  The ultimate goal is for the user to select the records / fields and for the macro to pull in the pre-formatted text from Access in to Word and have it look the way it was intended.  Ash

Comment: Again, why not use an Access form for users to enter formatted text, select records via listbox, combox, or subform and then output a report in PDF format? Why even use Word? If for editing purposes of text fields, do so in Access prior to export.

Comment: This is just one part in the process of pulling together a finished document - the text has to go from Access to Word where it is added to a full proposal document, there is no way around this.  Can you help me with getting this to work?

Comment: can you use Word to retain the formatting instead of a memo field in Access?  That's how mail merge works.

Comment: Answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350527/copy-rtf-text-from-access-to-word-table-using-vba