# How to get rich text, which Access formats using HTML, into a Word doc

Tags: html, ms-access, formatting, vba, richtext

I am copying formatted text from a Word document into a rich text field in Access.

Later I want to use VBA to create a new Word document and write the text as formatted to it.

The problem is, Access saves rich text with HTML formatting. And when you try to write that to a doc or docx, you see the text and its HTML tags.

How do I write the text to a Word document so that it retains the intended formatting and doesn't show HTML codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I have found that works (without modifying the input string) is to write the HTML to a temporary file, then use `.InsertFile` to load that file into the word document. Here's a sub that takes the input argument and puts it into a new Word document:

```vb
Sub WriteToWord(myHtmlFormattedText as String)

    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document    
    Dim fso As Object  ' FileSystemObject
    Dim f As Object  ' TextStream
    Dim tempHtmlFile As String

    ' Write your HTML content to a temp file:
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    tempHtmlFile = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\" & fso.GetTempName & ".htm"

    Set f = fso.CreateTextFile(tempHtmlFile, True)
    f.Write myHtmlFormattedText
    f.Close
    Set f = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing


    ' Set up word object
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    With objWord
        .Visible = True
        Set doc = .Documents.Add
    End With

    'Add HTML file contents:
    objWord.Selection.InsertFile tempHtmlFile

    ' Show the doc
    doc.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice. `tempFileSpec` should be `tempHtmlFile`, I think.

Comment: (cc: @Andre ) Yup. Good answer. It's [what I would have suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16354580/2144390). ;)

Comment: Ouch. So that's where `tempFileSpec` comes from. Well, I guess good code or algorithms are the lore of programmers, handed down through generations, not caring about attribution or things like that. @GordThompson

Comment: @Andre It's all good. Fortunately there are lots of "Internet points" to go around. :)

Comment: Thanks @Andre - I was afraid I'd miss a substitution and I probably missed that 3 times in my review!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will help, but there are a few different pasting features in Microsoft Word (in thee upper left corner of the 'Home' tab) that many people overlook

[image: Paste Options]

This allows you to paste with/without formatting. Not sure if it will solve your specific issue, but hopefully!